# If $Y$ is a sub-Gaussian random variable, must $Y-E(Y\mid X)$ be also sub-Gaussian?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, subgaussianity

> **Question.** If $Y$ is a sub-Gaussian random variable, must the regression residual $\varepsilon=Y-E(Y\mid X)$ be also sub-Gaussian? That is, whether there exists some constant $\sigma>0$ such that $E\big( e^{\lambda \varepsilon} \big) \leq e^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2}$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

In terms of the variance, it is well known that $\mathrm{var}(\varepsilon)\leq \mathrm{var}(Y)$. However, I can't find out a way to prove (or disprove) the sub-Gaussianity of $\varepsilon$ when $Y$ is sub-Gaussian. I wonder if $\varepsilon$ is always sub-Gaussian, by the sub-Gaussianity of $Y$, and maybe plus some additional requirements on $X$ (such as $X$ is also sub-Gaussian) or $E(Y\mid X)$ (such as $E(Y\mid X)$ is linear).

Comment: The question isn't well-defined, because $\varepsilon$ has a *bivariate* distribution.  If $X$ is not subgaussian, then in what sense would you hope for $\varepsilon$ to be subgaussian?

Comment: @whuber I have updated the question by providing the definition of the sub-Gaussianity of $\varepsilon$. Actually, although $\varepsilon$ is generated by a bivariate distribution, I suppose it can be treated as a random variable with a univariate distribution.

Comment: It turns out the statement is true, with a proof provided in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581889/if-y-is-a-sub-gaussian-random-variable-must-y-ey-mid-x-be-also-sub-gaussi.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with linear regression - the answer is yes, $\epsilon$ is indeed subG.

First and most obvious, $E[\epsilon]=E[Y]-E[E[Y|X]]=0$ by law of total expectation. Then, according to [Vershynin](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html), all you need to prove is the bound on the MGF of $\epsilon$.

Now, if you're modelling linear regression then $E[Y|X]=\hat{Y}\sim\mathcal{N}$, which means this is a subG variable as well and by Hoeffding's lemma we get that their sum is also subG.

This won't hold for Poisson regression, as the Poisson distribution is not subG.

**Edit:**

The thing with subG property is this: you need the distribution to fulfill that, from a point $\lambda>0$, the probability tail $P(|Y|>\lambda)$ is lighter than the Gaussian tail. This is usually the case when $Y$ is some variant of Gaussian or when it is bounded. If $Y$ is subG with variance proxy $\sigma^2$ then by definition  of regression (classic, not Bayesian) we get that $\hat{Y}$ has subG distribution with the same proxy, hence the residual is subG with this proxy as well. The only condition here is that $E[Y|X]=E[Y]$ - that is, $\hat{Y}$ should be an unbiased estimator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your Poisson regression example, $Y$ itself is not sub-Gaussian. But I wonder if it is possible $\varepsilon$ is not sub-Gaussian when $Y$ is sub-Gaussian.

Comment: see edit regarding tails and condition

Comment: The statement "by definition of regression (classic, not Bayesian) we get that $\widehat{Y}$ has sub-Gaussian distribution with the same proxy" seems less obvious to me. Would you please provide a proof or a reference for this?

Comment: When constructing a GLM model, the most basic assumption is $\hat{Y}_i=E[Y_i|X_i]$. If, for example, we discuss linear regression then the general model is $y_i=x^T_i\beta+\epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. It then follows that due to the unbiasedness nature of $\hat{y}_i$, we get $y_i-\hat{y}_i=e_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.